# how to custom value which will be exported?

Tags: magento2, grid, css, export, importexport

I have a grid and buttons for exporting like this.

[image]

There is field status in my grid.  The value is 1 or 0. After exporting the grid, the value of this status is 1 or 0 in the CSV file. How can I make this value become "Yes" when the status is 1 and "No" when the status is 0 in the CSV?

Comment: custom grid or magento default grid(like product grid,order grid etc)

Comment: This is a custom grid